# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' error on append tr to a table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, append, appendchild

I have below code :

```
  var counter = 3;
    function AddAddressRow() {
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><div>' +
            '<select class="dropdown-wrap k-rtl " id="ddlPrefix' +
            counter +
            '_1" style="width: 100px;">' +
            '<option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>'+
            '<option value="option2">Option 2</option>' +
            '</select> <br /><br/></div></td><td><div>' +
            '<select class="dropdown-wrap k-rtl " id="ddlPrefix' +
            counter +
            '_2" style="width: 100px;">' +
            '<option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>'    +
            '<option value="option2">Option 2</option>' <
            +'/select><br /></div></td><td><input style="width: 100px;"           
            id="txtAddress' + counter+'"/><br/><br/></td></tr>');
        counter++;
        $("table#AddressTable").append(newRow);
    }
```

at on click of below button

```
 <button  onclick="AddAddressRow();">+</button>
```

I caught TypeError:

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: Side note: look into existing templating frameworks like handlebarsJS instead of building HTML with string concatenation...

Comment: You have typo-related invalid syntax in your `newRow` string (note where the syntax highlighting goes wrong...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newRow is not returning a tr node.
Check the fiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wBrLa/82/light/)

Or try something like this:

```
var tr_ele = document.createElement('tr');
tr_ele.innerHTML = '>html here..<';
$("table#AddressTable").append(tr_ele);
```

Comment: thanks, i tried your code but it just return me a "true" , what i missed ?

Comment: The closing tag is <table/> should be  </table>

Comment: I think the string is messed up -- check the closing select tag. The '<' is outside the string quotes.

Replace the last 3 lines:
....
'<option value="option2">Option 2</option>' 
                +'</select><br /></div></td><td><input style="width: 100px;" id="txtAddress' + counter + '"/><br/><br/></td></tr>');